# How can I create a multilevel Polar Chart in JavaScript similar to the one in the provided picture?

Tags: javascript, charts, anychart, radar-chart

How can I bulid the polar area or culomm chart with more levels which I've drawn in the picture?
I tried anychart.com (https://playground.anychart.com/2384JaQV/21) but don't get any idea to come to result as shwon in my picture [Polar area chart with 2 Levels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLpyX.jpg).

I also tried differnt libraies but don't found any parameter to build this.